# Different layouts on Google TV?

Tags: android, layout, resources, google-tv

I'm converting a app made for Honeycomb tablets into a Google TV app. My main layout is called main.xml. It's in the layout folder. I created a new folder layout-notouch with a new main.xml to display when the app is run on Google TV. But when I run my app (on the Google TV Android SDK Addon) he is still using the main.xml from the normal layout folder and not from the layout-notouch. What am I doing wrong here?

---

Update: I figured out that the layout-notouch is not working. When I play the file in layout-large, it working. But this is not what I want. Should I send a bug report to Google about this?

---

Update: I entered a bugreport into the Android Project on Google Code. You can find it at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20087

Comment: Well, there is either an emulator bug or a documentation bug. [The documentation claims that `notouch` should work](http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_developing.html#Custom). OTOH, the documentation elsewhere indicates that Google TV supports the "faketouch" system feature, and I could imagine that this might cause Google TV to not utilize `notouch` resources.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I will send a bug to Google about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are suggesting that your resource qualifiers be layout-tvdpi-notouch (720) & layout-xhdpi-notouch (1080)

layout-large-notouch should also work.

Comment: I tried the layout-large-notouch and that didn't work either. But the big question remains why layout-notouch doesn't work?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/tv/optimizing-layouts-tv.html is a good place to look.  It suggests layout-land-large

Comment: Neither layout-tvdpi-notouch nor layout-xhdpi-notouch have any effect on Logitech Revue.  Get your facts straight!

Answer (score 1):

According to someone else at Google, there is a `television` resource selector, which was introduced with Android 3.2: https://plus.google.com/u/0/108284392618554783657/posts/Lf5g8nqw6s4

The documentation still hasn't been updated, but presumably this is the corresponding constant in `Configuration`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION

Comment: Yeah, but if you use that it would mean you exclude all Google TV Android 3.1 users. And I think there are still a lot out there.